# Objects do not retain the frame that I give then when using CGAffineTransforms with Core Animation

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm making a game where when a card is touched, it grows so that it is focused, and when you 'let go', it goes back to its original size and place.  This seems pretty standard, however, when I add cards and move the hand around to accommodate different numbers of cards, touching the card makes it go to its original place, and not to the new place.

This has been stumping me for a while now 
Any hints would be much appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

As far as your problem is not much clear I think the frames are not retained by the objects. This can be a problem if you are just assigning the frames to objects. You should try to set the frames of your objects. Then this will work if the frames positions are right.

Hope this will help. If I didnt get you pls be more clear.